# to set UTF-8 getting empty value

Tags: utf-8, phpmailer

In this php-script

```
$mail->CharSet   = 'UTF-8';
```

I'll get the following warning:

```
Creating default object from empty value.
```

Why - this should be set to UTF-8 for mailing.

Answer (score 0):

You've not posted any other code to provide context, but this just looks like you have not defined `$mail`, and when setting a property of an undefined object, that's what you'll get.